# Responsive HTML Menu - Centering Issue

Tags: html, menu, responsive

I'm having a huge brain fart when trying to center my menu.

I would sincerely appreciate any help someone can offer me.

My menu continues to align on the left but it needs to be centered.

Whenever I put a container around it, I lose my responsive functionality.

Here is my HTML

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script>
/* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav when the user clicks on the icon */
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<div class="logo"><img src="./images/logo.png"></div>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">

    <a href="#">Home</a>

    <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Gifts
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Home & Lifestyle
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Edible
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Wearable
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Toys & Games
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Blog
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">About Us
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- END TOP NAV -->

</div>
<!-- END HEADER -->
```

---

Here is my CSS

```
body {
margin:0 auto;
}
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.logo {
    display: block;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: .04em;
    font-family: 'Quattrocento Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: normal;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
.nav-wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background: #ffffff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    text-align:center;
}

/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #b9b9b9;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .07em;
    font-family: 'Quattrocento Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 19px;
}

/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.active {
  color: 000;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
  color:#b9b9b9;
}

/* Dropdown container - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the dropdown button to fit inside the topnav */
.dropdown .dropbtn {   
   text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .07em;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 19px;
    font-size:inherit;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #b9b9b9;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Style the dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Style the links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: #b9b9b9;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

/* Add a dark background on topnav links and the dropdown button on hover */
.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  color: 000;
}

/* Add a grey background to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu when the user moves the mouse over the dropdown button */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}


p {font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#333; line-height:20px;}
.thick { font-weight: bold;}
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 285px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.row {
  width: 945px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Clear floats after image containers */
.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

hr.short {
  width: 285px;
  height: 1px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #dedede;
  margin-top: 40px;

}



/* Responsive layout */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
  }

  .row {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Clear floats after image containers */
.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}


}
```

The menu keeps going to the left (probably the float:left) but I just can't get this to work.

Anyone able to be my hero for the day, please?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `flexbox` to center your menu:

```css
.topnav {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav {
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .responsive {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

As you were struggling to implement your desired solution despite my suggestions, and as I had some spare time today, I decided to prepare a minimal working example for you. I think you wanted to achieve something like this:

```css
.logo-placeholder {
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.content {
  margin: 20px 100px 0 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #EEE;
}

.header-navigation {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #CCC;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  list-style: none;
}

.subnavigation {
  display: none;
}

.navigation-item {
  position: relative;
}

.navigation-item:hover > .subnavigation {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo-placeholder"></div>
<nav class="header-navigation">
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li class="navigation-item">
      Top Nav Item 1
      <ul class="subnavigation">
        <li>Subitem 1</li>
        <li>Subitem 2</li>
        <li>Subitem 3</li>
        <li>Subitem 4</li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    <li class="navigation-item">
      Top Nav Item 2
      <ul class="subnavigation">
        <li>Subitem 1</li>
        <li>Subitem 2</li>
        <li>Subitem 3</li>
        <li>Subitem 4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navigation-item">
      Top Nav Item 3
      <ul class="subnavigation">
        <li>Subitem 1</li>
        <li>Subitem 2</li>
        <li>Subitem 3</li>
        <li>Subitem 4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navigation-item">
      Top Nav Item 4
      <ul class="subnavigation">
        <li>Subitem 1</li>
        <li>Subitem 2</li>
        <li>Subitem 3</li>
        <li>Subitem 4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<article class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quid ergo aliud intellegetur nisi uti ne quae pars naturae neglegatur? Quamquam ab iis philosophiam et omnes ingenuas disciplinas habemus; Sin laboramus, quis est, qui alienae modum statuat industriae? <b>Duo Reges: constructio interrete.</b> Idem iste, inquam, de voluptate quid sentit? Hoc etsi multimodis reprehendi potest, tamen accipio, quod dant. <b>Maximus dolor, inquit, brevis est.</b> </p>

<p><i>Non est igitur summum malum dolor.</i> <i>Sed haec omittamus;</i> Quia nec honesto quic quam honestius nec turpi turpius. Quid Zeno? </p>

<p><a href="http://loripsum.net/" target="_blank">Eiuro, inquit adridens, iniquum, hac quidem de re;</a> An me, inquam, nisi te audire vellem, censes haec dicturum fuisse? Cenasti in vita numquam bene, cum omnia in ista Consumis squilla atque acupensere cum decimano. At ille non pertimuit saneque fidenter: Istis quidem ipsis verbis, inquit; Est autem etiam actio quaedam corporis, quae motus et status naturae congruentis tenet; Quas enim kakaw Graeci appellant, vitia malo quam malitias nominare. </p>

<p>Nam si beatus umquam fuisset, beatam vitam usque ad illum a Cyro extructum rogum pertulisset. Semper enim ex eo, quod maximas partes continet latissimeque funditur, tota res appellatur. Eam tum adesse, cum dolor omnis absit; An me, inquam, nisi te audire vellem, censes haec dicturum fuisse? </p>

<p>Nam quibus rebus efficiuntur voluptates, eae non sunt in potestate sapientis. Immo istud quidem, inquam, quo loco quidque, nisi iniquum postulo, arbitratu meo. <i>Sed nunc, quod agimus;</i> Aliter homines, aliter philosophos loqui putas oportere? Universa enim illorum ratione cum tota vestra confligendum puto. Sed potestne rerum maior esse dissensio? An ea, quae per vinitorem antea consequebatur, per se ipsa curabit? <b>Quod quidem nobis non saepe contingit.</b> Dolor ergo, id est summum malum, metuetur semper, etiamsi non aderit; Nunc ita separantur, ut disiuncta sint, quo nihil potest esse perversius. </p>

<p>Sed quid attinet de rebus tam apertis plura requirere? Claudii libidini, qui tum erat summo ne imperio, dederetur. <i>Et ille ridens: Video, inquit, quid agas;</i> <b>Hoc est non dividere, sed frangere.</b> Tu enim ista lenius, hic Stoicorum more nos vexat. <b>Quid iudicant sensus?</b> Facile est hoc cernere in primis puerorum aetatulis. Sit enim idem caecus, debilis. Tum ille timide vel potius verecunde: Facio, inquit. <i>Comprehensum, quod cognitum non habet?</i> </p>

<p>Cur ipse Pythagoras et Aegyptum lustravit et Persarum magos adiit? Dicet pro me ipsa virtus nec dubitabit isti vestro beato M. Aliter enim nosmet ipsos nosse non possumus. Re mihi non aeque satisfacit, et quidem locis pluribus. Scio enim esse quosdam, qui quavis lingua philosophari possint; Familiares nostros, credo, Sironem dicis et Philodemum, cum optimos viros, tum homines doctissimos. </p>

<p>Atque hoc loco similitudines eas, quibus illi uti solent, dissimillimas proferebas. <a href="http://loripsum.net/" target="_blank">Murenam te accusante defenderem.</a> Cupiditates non Epicuri divisione finiebat, sed sua satietate. An vero, inquit, quisquam potest probare, quod perceptfum, quod. Huic ego, si negaret quicquam interesse ad beate vivendum quali uteretur victu, concederem, laudarem etiam; <b>Quae cum essent dicta, discessimus.</b> Quod maxime efficit Theophrasti de beata vita liber, in quo multum admodum fortunae datur. </p>

<p>Zenonis est, inquam, hoc Stoici. Itaque vides, quo modo loquantur, nova verba fingunt, deserunt usitata. <i>Aliter enim nosmet ipsos nosse non possumus.</i> Nec tamen ullo modo summum pecudis bonum et hominis idem mihi videri potest. Quid enim est a Chrysippo praetermissum in Stoicis? Alterum significari idem, ut si diceretur, officia media omnia aut pleraque servantem vivere. <i>Qui ita affectus, beatum esse numquam probabis;</i> Itaque si aut requietem natura non quaereret aut eam posset alia quadam ratione consequi. </p>

<p>Itaque sensibus rationem adiunxit et ratione effecta sensus non reliquit. Multoque hoc melius nos veriusque quam Stoici. <a href="http://loripsum.net/" target="_blank">Est enim effectrix multarum et magnarum voluptatum.</a> <b>Nihilo beatiorem esse Metellum quam Regulum.</b> Nos autem non solum beatae vitae istam esse oblectationem videmus, sed etiam levamentum miseriarum. </p>

<p><a href="http://loripsum.net/" target="_blank">Quaerimus enim finem bonorum.</a> Tenent mordicus. At iam decimum annum in spelunca iacet. Cur tantas regiones barbarorum pedibus obiit, tot maria transmisit? </p>

<p>Cum audissem Antiochum, Brute, ut solebam, cum M. <a href="http://loripsum.net/" target="_blank">Summum ením bonum exposuit vacuitatem doloris;</a> Aliis esse maiora, illud dubium, ad id, quod summum bonum dicitis, ecquaenam possit fieri accessio. Et ille ridens: Video, inquit, quid agas; Sed fortuna fortis; Facillimum id quidem est, inquam. Quid in isto egregio tuo officio et tanta fide-sic enim existimo-ad corpus refers? Eorum enim est haec querela, qui sibi cari sunt seseque diligunt. Sic enim maiores nostri labores non fugiendos tristissimo tamen verbo aerumnas etiam in deo nominaverunt. Quod autem ratione actum est, id officium appellamus. <b>Sin aliud quid voles, postea.</b> </p>


</article>
```

Comment: I CANNOT thank you enough!  I haven't heard of this approach before and need to educate myself on it.  Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: I am happy I helped and even more happy you want to educate yourself ! If I can recommend something for studying, it is this article: https://internetingishard.com/html-and-css/flexbox/ . You can also thank me by upvoting my answer. If you think the answer solved your problem, you can mark it as a correct one too. This way I get a few reputation points as a reward for helping you.

Comment: I upvoted it but I'm a new user so it's recorded but doesn't show until I do it 15 times.  This does cause a small issue on mobile though where my menu items don't align, basically making my dropdown responsive menu not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Let me see, give me a minute

Comment: It also got rid of my sticky menu; doesn't stick anymore with addition of this code.

Comment: Okay, I updated the answer, so that the items display correctly even on mobile, is it better now ? ;-)

Comment: No problem man, really ! :D no I don't, but I was glad to help. You could also now do a little cleanup of your code, because you don't need to use the floats any more and several other things possibly, but I will leave that up to you to find out (after you study the article). Again, you can help me by upvoting and accepting my answer (it's the "check" sign next to it). That is - if you believe it is the correct solution. Happy learning and coding @Michael!

Comment: It did eliminate my sticking to the top function, though, do oyu know how to get that back?

Comment: You could use `sticky` position for that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position  I am tired today, don't have energy anymore, you can try yourself though !

Comment: @Michael did you succeed ?

Comment: unfortunately not yet. I ended up scraping it and starting from scratch and meow hitting more issues... lol . I really appreciate your help from earlier.

Comment: We want it identical where the dropdown works, it's sticky and the logo shrinks upon scrolling... Just seems like it'd be way easier to do in WP

Comment: I prepared a code example for you with everything you need. You can always get back to it when your implementation starts having problems ! No need for wordpress ;-) I did not do the mobile part though here, as I believe this was not causing you any problems, and you can finish this yourself :P

Answer (score 0):

As my account is fairly new, I couldn't comment, but here it is anyway:

ajobi posted a nice solution and that is a great one for 2D rows of elements. You should take a look at CSS Grid as well. It does basically the same as Flexbox, but in 3 dimensions.